# Text fields set undisplayed do not retain their value

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a project where we have a lot of text fields that we fade in and out, all these fields are given an instance name and upon load i load variables from a server in JSON format, i parse this format and assign the array to all the instances names.

When i trigger a movieclip, fading in a element with the text, the text is not set. If i THEN trigger the data loading function, the text is actually loaded but it seems like Flash doesn't load the instances if the clips are not visible.

How can i fix this? Is this something that has to do with garbage collection?

Comment: Most likely it has something to do with those frames of your MC. If possible, switch base of your textfield holder to Sprite

Comment: It seems when i search through the root container for items to set, the only thing i find are those items that are displayed.

Comment: Ok, i think i found the problem but i don't know why it occurs. I have a empty frame in every MC before. It seems like the object isn't loaded if that empty container is there. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Well, you may try moving everything to 1 frame, drop anything else including actions layer (move it into *.as file) and declare class extending `flash.display.Sprite`, this should (I don't have Flash CS to test) declare additional variables with instance names defined at design, that will be initialized prior to running the constructor code, as well as making you sure that those text fields etc. exist at every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im sure its not garbage collection, If your using Action-Script 3 you need to "embed fonts" for your text to display:

Try debugging your code, is there any errors?

Im assuming if your using action script 2 the text boxes are out of reference at the time of loading vars, that would explain no error messages..Action script 3 would tell you that the text is underfined" hence being the error.

To Elaborate:

Your text_fields are not ready when your loading the variables, variables are loaded on  frame"1", text field don't exist until later so...you will need to store the variables until your textfields are ready.

Comment: The error occurs when there is nothing in the first frame on the movieclip, if i move everything to the first frame, everything is loaded correctly.

Comment: I changed my answer do you follow what i mean

Comment: No the project is built in AS3. I only did the backend before but our Flash guy is really sick so i have to step in on this and fix some bugs for release.

Comment: if you like you can send me the fla i could look at it

Comment: Variables are loaded separately in another class and they wait for stage completion. I have also tried loading the vars once every 5 sec to check if time is an error. It is not. The problem is that the refuse to load if the textfield isn't on a frame at the moment.

Comment: that is correct, flash will only display when the item is present... im suprised your not recieving compile errors

Comment: No errors. I ofc check in the backend loader if the thing is present. The old "design" file didn't have the problem since everything was made on frame 1 but i wrote the case anyway in the loader. I will just have to manually move stuff then.

Comment: cool you came up with a solution, it always hard getting some other persons mess to clean